# как отформатировать текст в форме React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, react-native

я отправляю форму через сайт на telegram api но мне не нравится формат сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно каждый ${username}, ${comment} и ${phone} на новой строке

должно выглядеть так:

Имя: ${username}

Сообщение: ${comment}
Номер тел: ${phone}

`Имя: ${username} \n Сообщение: ${comment}  \n Номер тел: ${phone}`. -перенос с \n не работает

`<br>` тоже

Comment: Здесь на русском общаются

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Comment: В шаблонных строках в качестве переноса используется обычный перенос

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [white-space: pre-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS:

```js
function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("John")
  const [comment, setComment] = React.useState("Hey")
  const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState("123123")
  
  const full = `Имя: ${username} \n Сообщение: ${comment} \n Номер тел: ${phone}`
  return <div className="pre-line">{full}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.pre-line {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
```